# Convert comma's to point and as numeric, but only in a certain amount of variables

Tags: r, csv

So I have a df that looks like this with numeric values split as commas instead of points and they're classified as characters.

```
var0 <- c("There, are commas", "in the text, string", "as,well", "how, can", "i", "fix, this", "thank you")
var1 <- c("50,0", "72,0", "960,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
var2 <- c("40,0", "742,0", "9460,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
var3<- c("40,0", "72,0", "90,0", "1,30", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
...
var96 <- c("40,0", "742,0", "9460,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")

df <- data.frame(cbind(var0, var1, var2, var3))
```

I know how to convert every variable manually using gsub, but as you can see below I have about 96 of these. Added to that, I have additional variables that include text string and factor levels where the comma's don't need to be converted.

Any tips on this?

Thank you

Comment: When creating a data.frame, there is no need for `cbind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that only replaces the commas by decimal periods and removes all other dots if all characters present are digits 0-9, dots and commas.

```
commas2dots <- function(x){
  if(any(grepl("[^\\.,[:digit:]]", x))){
    x
  } else {
    y <- gsub("\\.", "", x)
    tc <- textConnection(y)
    on.exit(close(tc))
    scan(tc, dec = ",", quiet = TRUE)
  }
}

lapply(df, commas2dots)
#$var0
#[1] "There, are commas"   "in the text, string"
#[3] "as,well"             "how, can"           
#[5] "i"                   "fix, this"          
#[7] "thank you"          
#
#$var1
#[1]   50   72  960 1920   50   50  960
#
#$var2
#[1]   40  742 9460 1920   50   50  960
#
#$var3
#[1]  40.0  72.0  90.0   1.3  50.0  50.0 960.0
#
#$var96
#[1]   40  742 9460 1920   50   50  960
```

To change the data.frame's columns:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, commas2dots)
df
#                 var0 var1 var2  var3 var96
#1   There, are commas   50   40  40.0    40
#2 in the text, string   72  742  72.0   742
#3             as,well  960 9460  90.0  9460
#4            how, can 1920 1920   1.3  1920
#5                   i   50   50  50.0    50
#6           fix, this   50   50  50.0    50
#7           thank you  960  960 960.0   960
```

**Data**

```
var0 <- c("There, are commas", "in the text, string", "as,well", "how, can", "i", "fix, this", "thank you")
var1 <- c("50,0", "72,0", "960,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
var2 <- c("40,0", "742,0", "9460,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
var3<- c("40,0", "72,0", "90,0", "1,30", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
var96 <- c("40,0", "742,0", "9460,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")

df <- data.frame(var0, var1, var2, var3, var96)
```

Answer (score 0):

The tidyverse package is nice for this sort of thing.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
      # First, remove the points in your numbers b/c otherwise, you'll end up
      # with, e.g., "1.920.0"
      mutate_all(.fun = function(x) gsub("\\.", "", x)) %>% 
      # Next, replace all the commas with points and convert to numeric. Only do
      # this for the columns that don't contain text, though.
      mutate_at(.vars = vars(matches("var[1-3]")), 
                .fun = function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", x)))
```

Please note that, in the `mutate_at` call, I assumed that only the column "var0" contained text that you'd want to retain and I converted anything that matched the regular expression "var[1-3]" to numeric data and used points instead of commas. You'll need to adjust that regular expression as needed for your situation.